# How to figure out the maximum number of framebuffers in WebGL

Tags: webgl, framebuffer, webgl2

How do I get the maximum number of possibly allocated framebuffers in WebGL? I assume you use `getParameter` but I don't know what to pass in it. For the maximum amount of color attchements I know I can pass `MAX_DRAW_BUFFERS_WEBGL`, but i don't know about allocated framebuffers.

Also what does the WebGL 1.0 and 2.0 specs say for the minimum required number of framebuffers possibly allocated and color attachments that can be drawn to and attached at once?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no hard limit on framebuffers, after all they're not resource intensive, their attachments are.

As to the number of supported color attachments, according to [section 6.8](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#6.8) in the [WebGL 1 spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/):

> The following combinations of framebuffer object attachments, when all of the attachments are framebuffer attachment complete, non-zero, and have the same width and height, must result in the framebuffer being framebuffer complete:

```
COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE texture
COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE texture + DEPTH_ATTACHMENT = DEPTH_COMPONENT16 renderbuffer
COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE texture + DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT = DEPTH_STENCIL renderbuffer
```

So that's minimum required number of color attachments: `1`

There's no required minimum number of enabled draw buffers(=attachments) in the [WebGL 2 spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/) nor in the [ES 3.0 spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf), instead it's implementation specific and needs to be queried through the means you already mentioned, I believe the defacto minimum to be `4` though.